# Product Name Recognition from Informal Text

Tags: nlp, product, named-entity-recognition

About 5 years ago, I re-trained Stanford NER and it works somewhat, but new products often get missed. At that time, I retrained the entire NER model. What I would really like to do is to fine tune the Stanford NER model. Can that be done now?  Someone asked that before but the answer is not clear to me.

[How to create incremental NER training model(Appending in existing model)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114476/how-to-create-incremental-ner-training-modelappending-in-existing-model)

Also related:
[How to extract brand from product name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047569/how-to-extract-brand-from-product-name)

The most recent paper I can find is this: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.904.3818&rep=rep1&type=pdf

I tried the NER command on https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/caseless.html and it gave an error indicating "english-caseless-left3words-distsim.tagger" etc. could not be found. Is there a place for download trained models?

(OK. The models are included in stanford-english-corenlp-2018-02-27-models.jar)

Comment: Is there a special reason for using Standford model? Spacy NER model has the capability you ask for

Comment: Here is the reason: http://blog.thehumangeo.com/twitter-ner.html